# Ephemeral Kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running Kubernetes on a bunch of bare metal machines, with a NetApp FAS for NFS storage. The nodes are all Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, provisioned with Ansible.

Ideally, I'd like to have a disaster-tolerant environment, meaning that as long as the NetApp-to-tape backup works I can completely recover from any kind of machine or infrastructure loss (been burned once by a datacenter fire, you remember the big one).

For the applications running *inside* Kubernetes and the few services that run outside of it (which is just two DNS servers and an UDP service), that works fine: mount the directories that hold the data of the services via NFS (or in the case of k8s services, use Trident-backed PVCs), run a snapshot on the NetApp every 24h, that's it. Tested, works fine.

The problem is the Kubernetes nodes themselves - I don't even know on just how many different ways that thing stores its data. There's stuff in `/var/lib/kubelet/`, there's config and a whole PKI in `/etc/kubernetes`, calico's stuff in `/etc/cni/net.d/calico-kubeconfig`... is there any guidance on how to make a disaster-proof k8s deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [**Disaster Recovery Preparedness for Your Kubernetes Clusters. August 11, 2020 | By: Rancher Admin**](https://www.suse.com/c/rancher_blog/disaster-recovery-preparedness-for-your-kubernetes-clusters/)

And there is an other reference: [**Webinar: Effective Disaster Recovery Strategies for Kubernetes**](https://youtu.be/LpDMzhhEYfc)